# Mobile access to SP2010 intranet

Tags: 2010, mobile, intranet

The mobile app that our organization uses for intranet access doesn't support automatic Windows authentication. Users can see our SP2010 intranet in the app only by manually entering their Windows username and password along with the domain.

From a practical standpoint, only a few pages and libraries in SP need to be available on employees' mobile devices. Here are two ideas I came up with. Which one is more feasible?

1. For each desired list or library, populate another library that is set to anonymous access.
2. Use a list as an external data source for a non-SP site behind our firewall. All my research into external data sources involve importing into SP, not exporting from the platform.